# Can transcendental functions be approximated to algebraic ones.

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-functions

I just wanted sin(x) in terms of algebraic operations like addition,multiplication,etc.
And can we extract that from the right angled triangle sides ratio definition, sine=altitude/hypotenuse
or we have to involve calculus.

Answer (score 2):

If an infinite polynomial is fine with you, we can use the Taylor Series for $\sin(x)$.  It is derived though calculus, however.

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$